# Junction table relations data

Tags: postgresql

I need to create a table that stores data about users in a company. For that, I want to use a junction table. I figured out there are two ways:

Variant 1:

```
create table user_company
(
  id uuid default uuid_generate_v4() not null primary key,
  is_chief boolean not null,
  is_worker boolean not null,
  is_trainee boolean not null,
  user_id uuid references user on delete cascade not null,
  company_id uuid references company on delete cascade not null,
)
```

Variant 2:

```
create type enum_users_role as enum ('chief', 'worker', 'trainee');

create table user_company
(
  id uuid default uuid_generate_v4() not null primary key,
  state enum_users_role not null,
  user_id uuid references user on delete cascade not null,
  company_id uuid references company on delete cascade not null,
)
```

In my case, I know for sure that an user can only be in one of three states. Are there any benefits for choosing one over another? Storage? Extensibility?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: The Booleans seem to describe the role a person has in the company but the enum name suggests it describes who has created the record. How does that describe the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second method seems preferable because the structure implicitly makes clear that the three states cannot occur together.

You should have a unique constraint on `(user_id, company_id)` – if you can live with a multi-column primary key, make this the primary key and ditch the superfluous `id`.